# Huge Mysql Update Queries Are Infalting My mysql-slow.log

Tags: mysql

I have a Wordpress website with Woocommerce.

Here's my server specs

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.28, for Linux (x86_64)
Php version 7.2
Apache 2.4
Wordpress 5.2.4
Woocommerce 3.7.0

My mysql-slow.log is becoming bloated, it's up to 64GB at the moment. These weird queries get listed in the log

```
# Time: 2019-11-24T06:25:16.360486Z
# User@Host: <user> @ localhost []  Id: <id>
# Query_time: 0.503146  Lock_time: 0.156594 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
use mysite-wp-db;
SET timestamp=1574576716;
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'a:275641:{i:0;b:0;s:32:\"b2777be5bac9ffade516827f6877a693\";a:0:{}s:32:\"7e018046da3d7596b61dac36ebee7fb1\"
```

The file looks like the image below, but goes on for several lines. I've tailed out the last 10 lines of the slow log and this line alone makes this file around 45MBs.

I'm looking into what's causing this but I can't find a specific reason, the query isn't helping either, so any help would be much appreciated.

[image: mysql-slow.log]

I'm also seeing a ton of traffic from Hong Kong, trying to filter a ton of different products on my site. All of the Hong Kong requests are /shop?filter_flavours requests.

[image]

Comment: What time length did you set the log time to log at? The lengths in the example seems very fast.

Comment: I just have it set as default.

Comment: a 45 MB update is always slow but use the maintenance on it for example flush it afterwords. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/log-file-maintenance.html

Comment: What does `long-query-time` have? `0.5` doesn't seem like it should be an issue. Is the issue a DOS or long queries?

Comment: The issue is that my mysql-slow.log file size is up to 65GBs due to these Mysql queries.

Comment: So empty the log file and set the `long-query-time` to something reasonable `truncate -s 0 file`

Comment: Alight, I'll go ahead and do that, but I'm trying to figure out what's going on with the mysql and filter queries, any ideas on that?

Comment: I don't know what wordpress is doing. It might just be that your `long-query-time` is set to low and logs every query.

Comment: The image seems to show the middle of a JSON string.  Show us the start of a couple of queries.  The first several lines of a slow log 'entry' are the most informative.  Perhaps this is part of the `SELECT` for a dump?  When do you backup the system?  Can you turn off the slowlog during the backup?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of what you have by running `pt-query-digest` to see what the "slow" queries are.  Grab the 'worst' few and optimize them.

Do `FLUSH LOGS;`  In newer versions, this will 'rotate' the file and let you delete the 65GB file.

Please provide

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%slow%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'long%';
SELECT @@version;
```

so we can advise on the settings.